# SQL state [null]; error code [0]; The statement did not return a result set.; nested exception is com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, spring-jdbc

I have next query:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temptablename') IS NOT NULL 
    SELECT TOP 1 someField FROM #temptablename ORDER BY someField DESC
```

I execute it using jdbcTemplate of Spring JDBC:

```
List<String> resultList = jdbcTemplate.queryForList(query);
```

Most of all it works perfectly, but sometimes it fails with (temp table is created before and exists, there are no any SQL exceptions in logs (for instance, connection is closed , etc.)):

```
`StatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temptablename') IS NOT NULL SELECT TOP 1 someField FROM #temptablename ORDER BY someField DESC]; SQL state [null]; error code [0]; The statement did not return a result set.; nested exception is com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The statement did not return a result set.`
```

What can be the cause of this exception generating?

I would appreciate any assistance.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I need to get list of records. execute() does not return anything.

Comment: Something doesn't match here. If the path through your code is supposed to create and populate the temp table before this query executes, then there should be no need to check for existence. But if this "set" of queries is implemented separately such that the creation step uses one connection while this step uses another, then there is the obvious chance that the temp table is dropped between the 2 steps. Either fix that or change this query by adding an else clause that returns an empty resultset. At least that's my guess.

Comment: temp table is only visible to the db session that creates it. The query does not return a resultset because the temp table does not exist (IF ...).

Comment: @PeterHe, Could you, please, explain me why I do not always catch this error but only sometimes?

Comment: @SMor If there are no data, then jdbcTemplate.queryForList(query) returns empty list (I checked it). Could you, please, be more specific on how can I add else clause that returns an empty resultset? Thanks !

Comment: @KateLeveret If you created the temp table in one jdbc call, and then do the query in another jdbc call, you may use  different connections from the pool and ends up with this exception

Comment: @PeterHe, Thank you for the explanation. How can I handle it, because I have some application proceeding  between temp table creation, loading data and execution this query?

Comment: @KateLeveret In this case, you may just use physical tables as working tables. Follow a good naming convention, and drop them after they are not required. You can suffix GUID as part of the the table name to make them unique, and can also create a dedicated schema e.g. tmp in the database, and place all those tables in this schema.

Comment: @PeterHe I dropped temp table before execution this query and got the exception: nested exception is `com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: 
Invalid object name '#temptablename'`. So, that means that table exists and there is other cause why I got exception on select execution.

Comment: You mentioned most of the time it works so you will see this error most of the time if you drop the temp table

Comment: @PeterHe You do not understand me correctly. I mean I have added additional line of code to drop table before select query execution and after that I catch an exception `Invalid object name '#temptablename'`. So, that means if temp table is not exist I will see invalid object exception instead of `The statement did not return a result set.`

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean.